# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.starSide')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

These are my code:

```
class StarListScrollViewCell extends Component{
static propTypes = {
    dateSource : React.PropTypes.array
}
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
        starSide : 20,
    }
}
addStar(){
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
     this.setState({starSide: this.state.starSide + 10});
}
componentWillMount() {
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
}
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white' , height: 70 , width : Dimensions.get('window').width,flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red' ,width:Dimensions.get('window').width/7,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}
            onPress = {this.addStar()}>
                <Image source={require('./star-gray.png')}
                       style ={{width:this.state.starSide,
                           height:this.state.starSide,
                           justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>

                </Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

I encountered a error when I click the button.And I write it referencing https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/animations.html

Comment: As @owaishanif786 mentioned you need to bind the method to the current component, but also when you call it do: `onPress = {this.addStar}` without parentheses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.state is undefined during onPress event in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123387/this-state-is-undefined-during-onpress-event-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind this to addStar as this context is changed when you called from event handler.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
        starSide : 20,
    }

     this.addStar = this.addStar.bind(this);


}

<TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.addStar()}>
```

Also above line will run fine but it will be called immediately may be which is not your purpose so instead use

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.addStar}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind context to your handler when using it in JSX and when you set `onPress` prop don't call the method, just pass reference to it:

```
 <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red' ,width:Dimensions.get('window').width/7,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}
            onPress = {this.addStar.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

React handlers are not automatically bound to the element/class they are in.

Change  `onPress = {this.addStar()}>` to

```
 onPress = {this.addStar.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding you can just use arrow functions:

```
addStar = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
     this.setState({starSide: this.state.starSide + 10});
}
```

And then:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addStar}>
```